# How to cross-compiling on Linux to Windows by GHC?

Tags: haskell, gcc, cross-platform, ghc, haskell-platform

Is it possible to compile a `foo.hs` file by GHC in Ubuntu to an executable targeting windows or other platforms?

Comment: I feel that you don't actually mean a cross-platform executable (which would run on multiple platforms), rather cross-compiling on Linux to Windows, right?

Comment: @H2CO3, I am sorry, you are right! Please allow me to change the title.

Comment: Ah, OK, I see what you want now.